# Retrofit @ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @FieldMap keys must be of type String: K (parameter #2)

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

This exception only occurred in one phone while other phones are ok. How should I fixed this? Is this exception related to the proguard?

Detail exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @FieldMap keys must be of type String: K (parameter #2)
for method g.d
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy0.d(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given no code snippet I suggest you to change your service method signature from `@FieldMap HashMap/Map params` to `@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> params`. And calling it like this

```
HashMap<String, String> params = ServiceUtil.getInstance().getDefaultParams();
                                maisService.fetchAjudaCategorias(params)
```

This should work fine.